# Most recurring weekday of a datetime2 fiel on a Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, weekday

I have a Table with Orders. On that table I have a field CreatedAt (datetime2). Is it possible to create a select query that shows me how many orders there have been made on every weekday? Not between to dates but over the hole table.

Like:
Monday:52
Tuesday: 16
...
and so on for all 7 days in a week.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
select datepart(weekday,CreatedAt) weekday,count(*) count
from Table
group by datepart(weekday,CreatedAt)
```

Comment: Thx. Exactly what i needed. :)

Comment: @Sknecht FYI - datename() would return the actual weekday name ... Monday, Tuesday, ...